# sometimes, strange audio distortion(peeping, scratching), ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, hda-intel

i have a problem with my sound in ubuntu 12.04(64bit).
the problem is, that sometimes out of nowhere, when switching songs, or playing youtube videos, changing volume with my keyboard buttons, that the sound gets distorted(peeping, scratching). i dont know if it is related, but when i skip through music in rythmbox, there is also a little scratching noise.

i can sometimes temporarly fix it:
for youtube videos, i refresh the page, and sometimes it works agian normal, mostly not.
for audio playback with rythmbox, i have to pause the song for sometime, and resume it, and hope that it works.

before all that,i have changed my soundcard to "Analog Surround 5.1" in the sound settings from ubuntu, but i also used alsamixer to change it from 2 channels to 6 channels, since changing in ubuntu sound settings alone wasnt enough to make the other speaks work.

i use a ASUS P8-H61-M LE B3 Revision Motherboard. which has a built in surround soundcard.
here is lshw -c multimedia output:

```
Beschreibung: Audio device
Produkt: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
Hersteller: Intel Corporation
Physische ID: 1b
Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1b.0
Version: 05
Breite: 64 bits
Uhr: 33MHz
Fähigkeiten: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
Konfiguration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
Ressourcen: irq:43 memory:f7f00000-f7f03fff
```

Comment: Odd... I've never had an issue with snd_hda_intel. Let me see if I can find the configuration options for you.

Comment: I have an issue as well (14.04.5 64-bit, Latitude E5570): after resume, everything sounds like it's coming from the bottom of a well, kind of.

Answer (score 1):

After days with that problem and google it, I fixed with this link https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

When the ALSA driver are loaded, it does a BIOS probe to try to figure out what version of the sound card you have. It's possible that perhaps the BIOS is either misdetecting or not detecting the card and using a generic model. So, in order to try out the other models you have to force the models with modprobe.

Try adding the following line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (at the bottom):

`options snd-hda-intel model=asus`

The models listed in the ALSA documentation that may be pertinent to you are:

- asus: 3-jack (ASUS mobo)
- asus-w1v: ASUS W1V (Probably doesn't apply to you)
- asus-dig: ASUS with SPDIF output
- asus-dig2: ASUS with SPDIF output (using GPI02)

Others you might try:

- 3stack: 3-jack in back and a headphone out
- 3stack-digiout: 3-jack in back, a HP out and a SPDIF out
- 5stack: 5-jack in back, 2 jack in front
- 5stack-digiout: 5-jack in back, 2 jack in front, a SPDIF out
- 6stack: 6-jack in back, 2 jack in front
- 6stack-digiout: 6-jack in back with a SPDIF out

Experiment with those (as they apply to your motherboard) and let me know how it turns out. I can update my answer if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sed 's/; default-sample-rate = 44100/default-sample-rate = 96000/g' -i /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

That and `sudo gedit /etc/pulse/default.pa` and adding `tsched=0` to `load-module module-udev-detect` so it becomes `load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0` solved the issue for me.

For reference, the commands were put to my attention at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling.

Comment: Should the system be rebooted when those settings change or is there a way to load the new settings live?

Comment: @TomislavNakic-Alfirevic Pulse can be restarted by `pulseaudio -k`.